# [Laravel]Yesterday create-function for post is working, but it didn't work now

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, post, authorization

I had learned to make simple application using laravel yesterday and I just decided to check whether the things i have done previously are working or not..

When i used a create-function on Post.. it did not save (didn't work) on that and did not have error message...

I had make this simple apps yesterday, and it worked well

I used authorize function in this... this is sample code for create-function:

**PostController.php**

```php
public function store()
{
    $this->authorize('create', Post::class);
    
    $inputs = request()->validate([
        'title'=>'required',
        'post_image'=>'file', //mime: jpeg, png
        'body'=>'required'
    ]);
    
    if( request('post_image') ) {
        $inputs['post_image'] = request('post_image')->store('images');
    }

    auth()->user()->posts()->create($inputs);
    
    session()->flash('post-create-message', 'Post was Created ' . $inputs['title']);
    return redirect()->route('post.index');
    
public function create()
{
    $this->authorize('create', Post::class);
    
    return view ('admin.posts.create');
}
```

**Post.php** (Post Model)

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function getPostImageAttribute($value)
{
    if (strpos($value, 'https://') !== FALSE || strpos($value, 'http://') !== FALSE) {
        return $value;
    }
    
    return asset('storage/' . $value);
}
```

**PostPolicy.php**

```php
public function create(User $user)
{  
    return $user->is($user);
}
```

routes **web.php**

```php
Route::get('/posts/create', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'create'])->name('post.create');
Route::post('/admin/posts', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'store'])->name('post.store');
```

**create.blade.php**

```xml
<form method="post" action="{{route('post.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" 
               name="title" 
               class="form-control" 
               id="title" 
               placeholder="Enter title">
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file">File</label>
        <input type="file" 
               name="post_image" 
               class="form-control-file" 
               id="post_image">        
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="body" class="form-control" id="body" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="" class="btn btn-primary" id="" placeholder="">Submit</
</form>
```

or what codes should i send?

P.S : I used this duplicate project just for safe

Comment: your store function is missing a closing bracket at the end (`}`) and your submit button is missing its closing tag (`</button>`)